# When installing a new program and having appwiz.cpl open it does not auto-refresh

Tags: windows-7, installation, appwiz.cpl

Is there a way to auto-refresh the programs in `appwiz.cpl` when installing a new program or is this not intended to work? Since I test software I often have to check if the (unattended) installation of a program succeeded. Whenever I come back to the system the program is not shown in the opened appwiz.cpl window. Pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> reveals whether the installation was successful or not. I would like to have that happen automatically. Does it depend on the installer? We use [install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html).

Comment: I suspect that this does not depend in the installer. It is more likely that refresh is not built in as it is time consuming to enumerate these programs when there are many installed.

Comment: You might use instead Revo Uninstaller Freeware - I'm positive that it refreshes the display on install.

Comment: Revo Uninstaller Freeware does the job. Add your answer as answer and you will get the points. Thanks.